# How to read pixel after the shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl

So on my program, I draw 2D rectangle using GLSL shader.
The rectangle is filled with texture. I have to use shader in order to do some computation and etc. 
Now, my question is that how can I access the pixel value of the scene (rectangle w/ texture) after the shader?
Basically, after it goes through vertex then fragment shader, it draws something in the scene and I want to access those scene as data like unsigned char* or pixels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glReadPixels` http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml

Make sure you use a FBO or PBuffer as render target to avoid data corruption.

Comment: Thanks! So just quick question...so frame buffer is the one that hold pixels data for the current scene ?

Comment: FBO are offscreen framebuffers, Google "Frame Buffer Object". I you render to a regular window, the read back content may be corrupted in various ways (this is due to the way, how OS will not process any pixels of a window that may be not visible to the user).